# radio button change not work properly ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have radio button with values: "By title" and "By actor". If user select By title the textbox auto-complete shows **list of movies** contain the word user type in the textbox, and if user select "By actor" the same textbox will show **list of actors**. Also, in case of "by title" there is a button "search movies by this title" which will open a new window showing list of movies contain the word that user inserted in the textbox. (The same button will be shown in case of "by actor", which shows list of movies by that actor)

### Problem:

If user select "by actor", and write an actor name in the textbox like "Tom Cruise", and then click the button "movies by this actor", a new window ("movielist.php") is opened showing list of movies by "Tom cruise". Now if then user change the radio button and select "by title" and write a title name like "Frozen" and click the button "movies by this title", the new window is opened but it shows list of movies by "Tom cruise" instead of list of movies contain word "Frozen".

This image may show my problem more clearly:

[image]

This is the code:

```
<div id="m_scents" class="field">
   <label style="margin-bottom:10px;" for="m_scnts"></label>
    <p>
     <input class="autofill4" type="textbox" name= "q27[]" id="q" placeholder="Enter movie, actor or director name here" />
     <input type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch" />
   </p>
 </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
      $("input[id='selectType']").change(function(){
               $("#q").val('');

               if ($(this).val() == "byTitle") {
                    $("#m_scents").show();
                    $("#q").focus();
                    $("#q").autocomplete({
                        minLength: 0,
                        delay:5,
                        source: "filmsauto.php",
                        focus: function( event, ui ){
                             event.preventDefault();  
                             return false;
                        },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                               window.selected = ui.item.value;
                        }
                    });

                 } else 

                   if ($(this).val() == "byActor"){
                             $("#m_scents").show();
                             $("#q").focus();
                             $("#q").autocomplete({
                                 source: "actorsauto.php",
                                 minLength: 2,
                                 focus: function( event, ui ){
                                      event.preventDefault(); 
                                      return false;
                                 },
                                 select: function (event, ui){ 
                                      window.selectedVal = ui.item.value;
                                 }
                             }); 
  } 

 $('#btnSearch').on('click', function (e) {
           window.textbox = $('#q').val();
           popupCenter("movielist.php","_blank","400","400");
  });
```

this is movielist.php:

```
<div id= "field"
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  var textbox = parent.window.opener.textbox;
 $.ajax({
         url: 'childfilm.php',
         datatype: "json",
         //I FEEL THE PROBLEM IS IN THE LINE BELOW WHERE ALL 3 VALUES ARE PASSED IN CASE OF CLICKING ANY BUTTON.. 
         data:{p:textbox}, 
         success: function(response) {     
                     $("#field").html(response);
                   }
        });
</script>*
```

and here is childfilm.php:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q'])){  //IN CASE OF BY ACTOR
  try{
    include('imdbConnection.php');
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT movieName FROM cast_movie WHERE castName = :q");
    $sql->execute(array(':q' => $_GET['q']));

    while($rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $option = '<a href=movie.php?title="' . $rows['movieName'] . '">' . $rows['movieName'] . '</a><br />';
       $html .= $option;

       }

    } catch(PDOException $e){
           echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
       }

   echo $html;       
   exit;
}

?>

<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html" charset=UTF8" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="filmstyle.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
 <div class= "movielist"> 
   <table id= "films">
     <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>year</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            if (isset($_GET['p']) && !empty($_GET['p'])) {  // IN CASE OF BY TITLE
                include('imdbConnection.php');
                $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT movieName, year, posterLink FROM film_info WHERE movieName LIKE :p");
                $query->execute(array(':p' => '%' . $_GET['p'] . '%'));
                if ($query->rowCount()) {
                        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
         ?> 
        <tr>
           <td><img class='imdbImage' id="image" src='imdbImage.php?url=<?php echo $row['posterLink']; ?>' alt="" /></td>
           <td><label id='year'><?php echo $row['year']; ?> </label></td>
           <td><a href="movie.php?title=<?php echo urlencode($row['movieName']); ?>"><?php echo $row['movieName']; ?></a></td>
        </tr>

                  <?php
                        endwhile;
                 } else {
                        echo '<td colspan="3">Sorry, there are no film matching your search</td>';
                    }
             }
                ?>
            </table>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i dont understand why you have so many buttons/variable/etc.. that almost do the same thing. You could have one button and 2 variables (searchText, searchType). And in your `PHP` just change your request based on the the type of research, no ?

Comment: @MamaWalter: Thanks for the point, you are right, I changed it to only one button :) but my question was something else..

Comment: Your problem is that the `$_GET['q']` is always set and not empty when it should be. If you use the same variables for your different research as i suggested and do the right request based on the type of reseach you will avoid your problem.

Comment: @MamaWalter: Thanks for help.. I updated the code, could you please kindly see it? (my problem is that I don't know what condition should I use in childfilm.php so that it could recognize when it should run the query to select movies by title.. and when run queries to get movies by actors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i tried to explain, you could do something like that.

AJAX:

the variable searchType should be update each time you change the research type.

```
var searchType = parent.window.opener.searchType; 
var textbox = parent.window.opener.textbox;
 $.ajax({
    url: 'childfilm.php',
    datatype: "json",
    data:{ q:textbox, t:searchType}, 
    success: function(response) {     
        $("#field").html(response);
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$searchText = (isset($_GET['q'])) ? $_GET['q'] : "";
$searchType = (isset($_GET['t'])) ? $_GET['t'] : ""; /* type of research */

 if($searchText !== "")
 {

  switch ($searchType) 
  {
    case 'byActor':
      $query = "SELECT DISTINCT movieName FROM cast_movie WHERE castName = :q";
      break;

    case 'byTitle':    
    default:
      $query = "SELECT DISTINCT movieName FROM film_info WHERE movieName LIKE :q";
      $searchText = "%".$searchText."%";
      break;
  }

  try
  {
    include('imdbConnection.php');
    $sql = $conn->prepare($query);
    $sql->execute(array(':q' => $searchText));
    $html = "";

    while($rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      $html .= '<a href=movie.php?title="' . $rows['movieName'] . '">' . $rows['movieName'] . '</a><br />';
    }

  } 
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }

   echo $html;       
   exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help.. I tried your code, but when I click a button "search", it opens an empty window! (in both cases: by title, or by actor).. I think it might be my mistake in defining searchType variable in the main page. I did like this: `window.searchType = $('input:radio[name=source]:checked').val();` in the search click function..

Comment: check in your browser console what the ajax request return, it could be syntax errors in my PHP, i haven't test it.

Comment: I checked the consule by F12, but there is no error :|

Comment: what is your browser? check what the request to `childfilm.php` return

Comment: the only thing I changed in your php code was `%:p%` in the second query to `%:q%`, I also changed case `actor` and `movie` to their actual name `byActor` and `byTitle`

Comment: this is the only error that I see with tail error.log: `File does not exist: /var/www/res/images, referer: http://localhost/page2.php
`  where page2.php is the first php script in my question ..

Comment: try to directly call your page: `http://localhost/childfilm.php?q="Tom Cruise"&t="byActor"` and see what is returned. Notice that you can check the return of your ajax call directly in the chrome (network tab) or FF console.

Comment: I added echo $selectText and it printed nothing... so I found in AJAX file I put p:textbox instead of `q:textbox`. Now: the error is : `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%?%' at line 1`

Comment: I don't know how to thank you! It works perfectly fine, THANK YOU :)